# ssrs 2008 page breaks between tablixes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a new ssrs 2008 report and I am going to have tweleve (12)  tablixes for twelve (12) different reports that a user can select on by using a parameter called 'optRPT '.
The main tablix will be setup by student number. The embedded tablixes are for 12 different reports.  I am planning to have 1 main tablix and embed the 12 tablixes within the main tablix .
The same parameters and dataset will be used for all the reports.

I want the12 tablixes to to be exported to separate pages and display as separate pages when the ssrs 2008 report is executing.  Page breaks will occur between when the student numbers change and when the reports change for each student.

Should I use conditional page breaks on a single rectangle, a rectangle embedded within a second rectangle, and/or in a table?

Thus can you tell me what you suggest I try to do to allow the page breaks to occur between when the student number changes and when the reports change for each student?
  Would you show me how to accomplish this goal using pictures, examples, and/or the code that is rquired?

Comment: Add a rectangle with `add a page break after` property selected between all tables.

Comment: This would always place a blank page at the end. I would like to avoid having a blank page ant first or at the end. How could I accomplish that goal?

Comment: I don't know if I get your issue correctly, please try to be more graphic.